# How can I remove escape characters from string? UTF issue?

Tags: ruby, xml, utf-8, escaping

I've read in a XML file that has lines such as

```
 <Song name="Caught Up In You" id='162' duration='276610'/>
```

I'm reading in the file with

```
f=File.open(file)
f.each_with_index do |line,index|
  if line.match('Song name="')
    @songs << line
    puts line if (index % 1000) == 0
  end
end
```

However when I try and use entries I find that get text with escaped characters such as:

```
"\t\t<Song name=\"Veinte Anos\" id='3118' duration='212009'/>\n"
```

How can I eliminate the escape characters either in the initial store or in the later  selection
`@songs[rand(@songs.size)]`

ruby 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text does not have 'escape' characters. The `.inspect` version of the string shows these. Observe:

```
> s = gets
Hello "Michael"
#=> "Hello \"Michael\"\n" 

> puts s
Hello "Michael"

> p s  # The same as `puts s.inspect`
"Hello \"Michael\"\n"
```

However, the real answer is to process this XML file as XML. For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'                                # gem install nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri.XML( IO.read( 'mysonglist.xml' ) ) # Read and parse the XML file
songs = doc.css( 'Song' )                         # Gives you a NodeList of song els
puts songs.map{ |s| s['name'] }                   # Print the name of all songs
puts songs.map{ |s| s['duration'] }               # Print the durations (as strings)

mins_and_seconds = songs.map{ |s| (s['duration'].to_i/1000.0).divmod(60) }
#=> [ [ 4, 36.6 ], … ]
```

Comment: fair enough.  call them 'codings'.  How can I remove them ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant A string with a double quote it in shows up as `\"` when inspecting the string, but it only has a double quote in it. A string with a newline in it has only a newline character (which you can remove from the ends with `.strip`), but shows as `\n`. What do you really want to do with your iTunes music store?

Comment: just playing with code.  It's actually a sample music file of 5000 songs.  I was unaware that it was the itunes format :)

Comment: [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is a delightful library for parsing and managing XML.